# Render Error: Cannot convert undefined value to object when using react-native-countdown-circle-timer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I can't seem to find which undefined value that I am passing into CountdownCircleTimer is causing this issue but I know it is not intSeconds as I have checked that it is an integer and even if I remove all the code wrapped in the CountdownCircleTimer tag it still causes the same error. The error seems to be being caused by the tag itself as I have checked all of the other components and it always returns this same error.

```
This error is located at:
    in CountdownCircleTimer (created by Break)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by Break)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by Break)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by ScrollView)
    in RCTScrollView (created by ScrollView)
    in ScrollView (created by ScrollView)
    in ScrollView (created by Break)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by Break)
    in Break (created by SceneView)
    in StaticContainer
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (created by SceneView)
    in SceneView (created by SceneView)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by DebugContainer)
    in DebugContainer (created by MaybeNestedStack)
    in MaybeNestedStack (created by SceneView)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by SceneView)
    in RNSScreen (created by AnimatedComponent)
    in AnimatedComponent
    in AnimatedComponentWrapper (created by InnerScreen)
    in Suspender (created by Freeze)
    in Suspense (created by Freeze)
    in Freeze (created by DelayedFreeze)
    in DelayedFreeze (created by InnerScreen)
    in InnerScreen (created by Screen)
    in Screen (created by SceneView)
    in SceneView (created by NativeStackViewInner)
    in Suspender (created by Freeze)
    in Suspense (created by Freeze)
    in Freeze (created by DelayedFreeze)
    in DelayedFreeze (created by ScreenStack)
    in RNSScreenStack (created by ScreenStack)
    in ScreenStack (created by NativeStackViewInner)
    in NativeStackViewInner (created by NativeStackView)
    in RNCSafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaProvider)
    in SafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaInsetsContext)
    in SafeAreaProviderCompat (created by NativeStackView)
    in NativeStackView (created by NativeStackNavigator)
    in PreventRemoveProvider (created by NavigationContent)
    in NavigationContent
    in Unknown (created by NativeStackNavigator)
    in NativeStackNavigator (created by App)
    in EnsureSingleNavigator
    in BaseNavigationContainer
    in ThemeProvider
    in NavigationContainerInner (created by App)
    in App (created by withDevTools(App))
    in withDevTools(App)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
    in main(RootComponent), js engine: hermes
```

break.js

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, ScrollView, SafeAreaView, Text, Button } from 'react-native';
import { CountdownCircleTimer, useCountdown } from 'react-native-countdown-circle-timer';

import { COLORS, icons, images, FONT, SIZES } from '../constants';

function Break({ route, navigation }) {
    const { time, sliderValue } = route.params;
    const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(true);

    const {
        path,
        pathLength,
        stroke,
        strokeDashoffset,
        remainingTime,
        elapsedTime,
        size,
        strokeWidth,
    } = useCountdown({ isPlaying: true, duration: 7, colors: '#abc' })

    console.log(time);
    console.log(sliderValue);

    const timeToSeconds = (time) => {
        const [hours, minutes, seconds] = time.split(':').map(Number);
        return hours * 3600 + minutes * 60 + seconds;
      };

    const test = timeToSeconds(time);
    const seconds = timeToSeconds(time) * (sliderValue / 60).toFixed(0);
    let intSeconds = parseInt(seconds);
    console.log(test);
    console.log(seconds);
    console.log(intSeconds);

    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: COLORS.lightBeige }}>
            <ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
                <View style={{ flex: 1, padding: SIZES.medium, }}>

                    <View style={{ alignItems: 'center', padding: SIZES.xLarge }}>
                        <CountdownCircleTimer
                            isPlaying={isPlaying}
                            duration={intSeconds}
                            updateInterval={1}
                        >
                            {({ remainingTime }) => <Text>{remainingTime}</Text>}
                        </CountdownCircleTimer>
                    </View>

                </View>
            </ScrollView>
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
};

export default Break;
```